# Ember.js new router 'history' implementation

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I think I checked all the documentation but I cannot use the 'history' implementation of the router. Anyone have a short example on how that should be used? Or, generally, how should router parameters be passed to the new router (logging too, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before defining the routes mapping, I would try to do something like

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: 'history'
})
```

Comment: That should have been obvious to me. Thx! I noticed though that enableLoggind does nothing this way.

Comment: Hum, about the logging, it has changed too. I will check what you have to use now.

Comment: Ok, it's not in the docs, but seeing https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L56 this should be when creating the App, add the LOG_TRANSITIONS property to true.

Comment: And that is a winner, too! Thx again!

Answer (score 5):

If I recall correctly, the newest router automatically instantiates App.Router for you, so rather than:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({ location: 'history' })
```

you want:

```
App.Router.reopen({ location: 'history' })
```

Answer (score 1):

I read through the ember.js source code and this seemed like the most sane way since the initialization occurs with the app.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  Router: Ember.Router.extend({
    location: 'history'
  })
});
```